# Como colocar peça de dominó à esquerda do 6|6 em C?

Tags: c

Estou com problemas no jogo domino que criei.

Consigo adicionar as peças à direita, mas quando tento adicionar à esquerda não executa como pretendido.

Aqui vai um exemplo:

> - **Jogada 1** -> Mesa 6|6
> - **Jogada 2** -> Mesa 6|6 6|2
> - **Jogada 3** -> Mesa 1|6 1|6 6|2 (substitui o 6|6 pela peça à esquerda)
> - **Jogada 4** -> Mesa 2|1 2|1 1|6 6|2 (continua)

Meu código:

```
void jogarpeca(pdomino vp[], int *n, pdomino t,char x) {
    (*n)++;
    int i;

    if(x=='f') {
        vp[*n]=t;
    }
    else {
        for(i=*n;i>=2;i--) {
            vp[i]=vp[i-1];
            vp[1]=t;
        }
    }
}

void retirarpeca(pdomino vp[], int *n, int t) {
   (*n)--;
   int i;

    for(i=t;i<=*n;i++) {
        vp[i]=vp[i+1];
    }
}

void jogar(jogador vj[],pdomino vp[], int *n, int j, int i, char c) {
    int ini,fim;

    ini=vp[1].lado1;
    fim=vp[*n].lado2;

    printf("NA MESA ");
    escreverpecas(vp,*n);
    printf("\n\n");
    escreverjogadores(vj);

    if(i==0) {
        printf("%s passa a sua vez...\n\n",vj[j].nome);
    }
    else {
        if(c=='i') {
            if(vj[j].pecas[i].lado2!=ini) {
                rodarpeca(&(vj[j].pecas[i]));
                printf("%s joga %d|%d no Inicio\n\n\n",vj[j].nome,vj[j].pecas[i].lado1,vj[j].pecas[i].lado2);
            }
            else {
                printf("%s joga %d|%d no Inicio\n\n\n",vj[j].nome,vj[j].pecas[i].lado1,vj[j].pecas[i].lado2);
            }
        }
        else {
            if(vj[j].pecas[i].lado1!=fim) {
                rodarpeca(&(vj[j].pecas[i]));
                printf("%s joga %d|%d no Fim\n\n\n",vj[j].nome,vj[j].pecas[i].lado1,vj[j].pecas[i].lado2);
            }
            else {
                printf("%s joga %d|%d no Fim\n\n\n",vj[j].nome,vj[j].pecas[i].lado1,vj[j].pecas[i].lado2);
            }
        }

        jogarpeca(vp, &(*n), vj[j].pecas[i], c);
        retirarpeca(vj[j].pecas,&(vj[j].totalpecas), i);
    }

    getchar();
}

void jogadas(pdomino vp[], int *n, jogador vj[], int j) {
    int ini,fim,i;
    int k=0;

    int p[9];
    char c[9];

    ini=vp[1].lado1;
    fim=vp[*n].lado2;

    for(i=1;i<=vj[j].totalpecas;i++) {
        if(vj[j].pecas[i].lado1==ini) {
            k++;
            p[k]=i;
            c[k]='i';
        }

        if(vj[j].pecas[i].lado2==ini) {
            k++;
            p[k]=i;
            c[k]='i';
        }

        if(vj[j].pecas[i].lado1==fim) {
            k++;
            p[k]=i;
            c[k]='f';
        }

        if(vj[j].pecas[i].lado2==fim) {
            k++;
            p[k]=i;
            c[k]='f';
        }
    }

    if(k==0) {
        jogar(vj,vp, &(*n), j, 0, 'x');
    }
    else {
        printf("funcao jogadas o k : %d",k);
        getchar();
        int x=k/*randi(1,k)*/;
        printf("funcao jogadas o x : %d",x);
        getchar();
        jogar(vj,vp, &(*n), j, p[x], c[x]);
    }
}

int jogar66(jogador vj[],pdomino vp[], int *n) {
    int j,i,j1,p1;

    for(j=1;j<=totaljogadores;j++) {
        for(i=1;i<=vj[j].totalpecas;i++) {
            if(vj[j].pecas[i].lado1==6 && vj[j].pecas[i].lado2==6) {
                j1=j;
                p1=i;
            }
        }
    }
    jogar(vj,vp,&(*n),j1,p1, 'f');
    return j1;
}

int ganha(jogador vj[]) {
    int jg,j;
    jg=0;

    for(j=1;j<=totaljogadores;j++) {
        if(vj[j].totalpecas==0) {
            jg=j;
        }
    }
    return jg;
}

int fecha(pdomino vp[], int n) {
    int p,q,i,c;
    c=0;
    p=vp[1].lado1;

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        if(vp[i].lado1==p) {
            c++;
        }

        if(vp[i].lado2==p) {
            c++;
        }
    }

    return c==8;
}

int acaba(jogador vj[], pdomino vp[], int n) {
    return ganha(vj) || fecha(vp, n);
}

int main() {
    srand(time(0));

    int i,j,p,x,contax;
    contax=0;
    pdomino vp[29];
    jogador vj[5];
    int n=0;

    criartodaspecas(vp);
    baralharpecas(vp);
    criarjogadores(vj,vp);

    x=1;
    printf("\n**********Jogada n' %d **********\n\n",x);
    j=jogar66(vj,vp,&n);
    getchar();

    while(!acaba(vj,vp,n)) {
        j=j+1;
        if(j==5) {
            j=1;
        }
        x++;

        printf("\n**********Jogada n' %d **********\n\n",x);
        jogadas(vp, &n, vj, j);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Antes de endereçar o problema perguntado, vou apontar alguns problemas em seu código:

- seu cálculo modular está problemático
  5 é equivalente a 0 mod 5, nao 1
  5 só é equivalente a 1 mod 4 ou mod 2
- em diversos pontos do seu código, você está considerando que o vetor inicia no índice 1, não no índice 0
  e ainda tem pontos de confusão em que você coloca coisas no índice 0
- 0 não é `NULL` para ser argumento de `time()`
- a função `jogarpeca()` tem duas responsabilidades, quando deveria ter apenas uma:

  1. colocar a peça na posição adequada (responsabilidade devida)
  2. aumentar o contador de jogadas (responsabilidade indevida)
- na iteração da operação `shift`, você está fazendo uma atribuição que não tem nada a ver

Com isso fora do caminho, vamos à resposta.

## Estrutura de dados

Para representar um mundo de dominó (não os jogadores), precisamos armazenar peças que são jogadas em ambas as extremidades. Mas não pode ser qualquer peça que podem ser jogadas, apenas aquelas que combinam com a peça já existente na extremidade (com exceção da primeira peça lançada, que é colocada por convenção).

Com essa descrição, precisamos ter duas operações para cada uma das extremidades:

- `peek`, onde se verifica qual a peça que está na extremidade
- `push`, que empurra a peça para a extremidade

Como dominó é um mundo linear, as extremidades são a esquerda e a direita, portanto temos 4 operações:

- `peek_left`
- `peek_rigth`
- `push_left`
- `push_right`

Para uma estratégia mais completa se faz necessário iterar sobre as peças, mas não vou entrar em detalhes sobre como fazer isso.

Precisamos então ter um esquema de armazenamento linear. C nos fornece duas alternativas para isso:

- posicionamento contíguo
- ponteiro para o próximo elemento

Essas alternativas são:

- vetor
- lista ligada

### Características satélites

Para conseguir acessar os extremos de maneira adequada, simplesmente armazenar o vetor/ponteiro para o primeiro elemento da lista não é o suficiente.

No caso do vetor, é necessário saber quantas posições já foram ocupadas. Também é adequado saber o tamanho total do vetor para estourar, para dar segurança ao programa.

Para listas ligadas, para ter acesso em `o(1)` e para facilitar a codificação, tanto para `peek` quanto para `push`, precisamos saber quem é o começo e quem é o final. Na primeira jogada, os ponteiros de início e fim da lista apontam para essa peça.

As peças tem duas propriedades cada:

- `left`, que indica o número à esquerda
- `right`, que indica o número à direita

É possível rotacionar uma peça, onde os valores `left` e `right` são trocados.

### Operação `peek`

- `peek_left`

  - vetor: `v[0].left`
  - lista: `inicio->peca.left`
- `peek_right`

  - vetor: `v[ocupados - 1].right`
  - lista: `fim->peca.right`

Caso seja desejado obter a peça, basta não obter o valor do campo.

### Operações de `push`

> nos exemplo, as peças `A`, `B` e `C` já estão no tabuleiro, nessa ordem. A peça a ser inserida é ω

Para fazer o `push`, as considerações são outras. No caso do vetor, dever-se-ia verificar se tem posição sobrando par incluir o novo elemento ou então, caso não haja, tratar de algum jeito a ausência de posições (seja alocando mais espaço ou retornando código de erro). Não vou me alongar nesse assunto, mas esteja ciente disso.

Para vetor, o `push_right` é apenas colocar na posição `v[ocupado]` ω e incrementar o valor de `ocupado`:

[image]

Para então obter o seguinte resultado:

[image]

Para lista, precisa-se apontar o `next` do nodo `C` para o nodo de ω, então apontar o fim para o nodo de ω.

[image]

Mais ou menos assim:

```
fim->next = novo;
fim = novo;
```

Para obter o seguinte resultado:

[image]

Para a operação de empurrar a esquerda, na lista é mais fácil. Você aponta o seguinte do nodo do ω para `A` e então aponta o início para o nodo ω.

Você começa assim:

[image]

Faz a operação de troca dos ponteiros:

```
novo->next = inicio;
inicio = novo;
```

Então obtém o seguinte resultado:

[image]

Para o caso do vetor, empurrar a esquerda primeiro exige-se que se faça um `shift` para ter uma posição livre à esquerda. Você começa com esse estado:

[image]

Faz o `shift`:

[image]

Para ter o seguinte estado intermediário:

[image]

Então basta fazer `v[0] = peca_nova`:

[image]

O único cuidado a ser tomado é que se precisa fazer o `shift` da direita para a esquerda:

```
int i;
for (i = ocupado - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  v[i + 1] = v[i];
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela sua resposta. Como estou a começar a aprender a programar em C, ainda não aprendi essas operações. 

Já consegui resolver o problema, tinha


for(i=t;i<=*n;i++)

{

    vp[i]=vp[i+1];
    vp[i]=t;

    }

e devia de ter for(i=t;i<=*n;i++)
    vp[i]=vp[i+1]; vp[i]=t; 

ou seja sem chavetas.

Comment: Acabei de terminar minha resposta. Tinha colocado em submeter sem querer. Deve responder suas dúvidas