# Calcular média Geométrica em consulta SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Exemplo de Tabela**

```
Campo - Valor
A     - 30,21
B     - 15,03
C     -  5,06
B     - 10,20
B     - 12,89
C     -  1,12
```

**Calculo média geométrica**

```
A = (30,21)^1/1
B = (15,03*10,20*12,89)^1/3
C = (5,06*1,12)^1/2
```

**Resultados**

```
A = 30,21
B = 12,23
C =  2,37
```

**Tentei algo assim**

```
POWER(POWER(10.00,SUM(LOG10(CAST(ANSDET.VALOR AS DECIMAL(30,2))))), 1/(CAST(COUNT(ANSDET.CAMPO)AS DECIMAL(10,2)))) VALOR,
```

A tabela possui cerca de 4000 registros, estou recebendo a mensagem:

> Ocorreu uma operação de ponto flutuante inválida.

Preciso da formula SQL que me retorne estes resultados das médias... Alguma ideia?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Que bom que eu não fui a única pessoa a passar pela necessidade do produtório em SQL por terras lusófonas.

Como o @Motta falou em sua confusa e pouco ilustrativa resposta, você pode usar o fato de que o log do produto é igual à soma dos logs e, então, transformar seu problema de *produtório* para *somatório* (com algumas adaptações que precisam ser anuladas posteriormente, claro).

Então, vamos mergulhar na terra dos logaritmos?

---

Essa resposta vai ser dividida em algumas seções, para ficar mais fácil seu manejo e poder segmentar a leitura. São eles:

1. de produtórios a somatórios e de volta de novo, com SQL
2. log do produto é a soma do log, mas por quê?
3. diga não a potência desnecessária: multiplicando `log(x)` por uma constante

> **NOTA**: como os logaritmos só são bem definidos com imagem real para números `> 0`, essa resposta falha miseravelmente se o conjunto de dados tiver pelo menos um número nessa situação, precisará fazer uma adaptação.
>
> Você pode conferir no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/40514) minha resposta para os dados informados na questão. Notou que a resposta para o caso `B` tá distinta da esperada? Pois bem, minha resposta é a [média geométrica verdadeira](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(15.03*10.20*12.89)%5E1%2F3), talvez tenha sido um erro de ponto flutuante/precisão na hora de escrever o resultado esperado.

---

## De produtórios a somatórios e de volta de novo, com SQL

Você tem um problema que é o cálculo de um produtório. Um exemplo de produtório bem
básico é o seguinte, para quem não está acostumado:

[image: produto de elementos em x do índice 0 ao 10]

O que isso quer dizer? Isso quer dizer que `y = x0 * x1 * x2 ... * x10`. O produto dos elementos do conjunto, um contraponto ao somatório que é a soma dos elementos do conjunto.

> Note como é extremamente semelhante a um somatório:
>
> [image: exemplo de somatório]
>
> No caso, o produtório é representado pela letra grega *pi*, cujo som lembra bastante o **P** do português e denota *produto*. Já o somatório é representado pela letra grega *sigma*, cujo som lembra bastante o **S** do português e denota *soma*.
>
> O somatório, então, é a mesma ideia do produtório porém usando o operador de soma: `y = x0 + x1 + x2 ... + x10`

Assumindo como verdade que `log(A*B) = log(A) + log(B)`, temos que `log(x0 * x1 * x2 ... * xn) = log(x0) + log(x1 * x2 ... * xn) = log(x0) + log(x1) + log(x2) ... + log(xn)`. Então, conseguimos daqui fazer um somatório dos logaritmos, porém, para substituir completamente, precisamos anular o logaritmo da jogada.

Mas, como? Simples, pela sua definição.

Na definição de logaritmo, temos que `e^x = n`, com `e` e `n` conhecidos. O logaritmo é a operação usada para encontrar o `x` da questão, logo `e^x = n <==> x = log(n)`.

A partir dessa definição, temos que `e^(log(x0 * x1 * x2 ... * xn)) = x0 * x1 * x2 ... * xn`. Justamente a definição de logaritmo. Porém, graças à propriedade `log(A*B) = log(A) + log(B)`, podemos substituir o produtório por somatório sem perder semântica: `e^(log(x0) + log(x1) + log(x2) ... + log(xn)) = x0 * x1 * x2 ... * xn`.

Como representar isso no SQL? Usando o exponencial do somatório dos logaritmos de dada coluna:

```
SELECT
  campo,
  exp(sum(log(valor))) as produtorio
FROM
  dados
GROUP BY
  campo
```

> Note que, como não é necessário explicitar a base, não estou usando nem `LOG10` nem tampouco `POWER(10, expoente)`, porém simples `LOG` e `EXP`

## Log do produto é a soma do log, mas por quê?

Sejam `A` e `B` dois números reais positivos quaisquer. Nenhuma outra imposição a eles é feita. Isso significa que há algum `a = log2(A)` e `b = log2(B)` que são os logaritmos de `A` e `B` respectivamente na base 2.

Se, por acaso, eu multiplicar `A*B` vou obter um número `C`, também real e positivo. Como `a = log2(A)`, isso significa que `A = 2^a`. Analogamente temos `B = 2^b`. Logo, `A*B = C = 2^a * 2^b`. Podemos simplificar a potência de 2 assim: `C = 2^(a+b)`.

E como seria se eu tirasse o `log2` de tudo?

Bem, sabendo que `C = 2^(a+b)`, temos que `log2(C) = a + b`. Porém não podemos nos esquecer que `C = A*B`. Logo, `log2(A*B) = a + b`. Substituindo as fórmulas iniciais de `a` e `b`:

```
log2(A*B) = log2(A) + log2(B)
```

Os cálculos foram feitos na base 2 por ilustração, mas poderia ser qualquer base, até mesmo φ.

## Diga não a potência desnecessária: multiplicando log(x) por uma constante

Mas você não quer simplesmente o produtório, mas sim a média geométrica. O produtório era apenas um meio para se chegar na média geométrica. A fórmula para média geométrica de um conjunto é dada pela seguinte fórmula:

[image: fórmula da média geométrica perfeitamente maquiada para esta resposta]

Ou seja, é a exponenciação do produtório pelo inverso da quantidade de elementos no produtório.

Se for transportar exatamente isso para o SQL fica algo assim:

```
SELECT
  campo,
  power(exp(sum(log(valor))), 1/count(*)) as media_geo
FROM
  dados
GROUP BY
  campo
```

Porém fica mais estranho exponenciar 2 vezes seguidas, não acha? Além de aparentar muita demanda computacional à toa? E, sim, está certo: tem trabalho sendo feito desnecessariamente aqui.

Tem uma propriedade muito importante da exponenciação que vamos usá-la agora: ela é distributiva sobre a multiplicação:

[image: propriedade distributiva da exponenciação sobre a multiplicação]

E tem outra propriedade bacana dos logaritmos: `log(a^b) = b * log(a)`. Daqui, podemos tranquilamente chegar nessa transformação:

[image: derivando a fórmula para usar logaritmos, somatórios, multiplicação e um único exponencial]

[image: mesma coisa do de cima, porém focando apenas nos elementos extremos]

Em SQL, ficaria assim:

```
SELECT
  campo,
  exp(sum(log(valor))/count(*)) as media_geo
FROM
  dados
GROUP BY
  campo
```

Comment: Utilizando estas formulas recebo o seguinte erro, "Ocorreu uma operação de ponto flutuante inválida."

Comment: Já obtive esse erro quando passava números negativos ou zerados para o log. Vou testar com mais calma a consulta contra a base de dados fornecida na sua pergunta.

Comment: A resposta do Quesado foi 10 , vou manter a minha como lembrete , jamais responda do tablet a preguiça te faz editar mal e porcamente .. esta solução via logaritmo e potenciação tem o problema de valores negativos ou muito grandes.

Comment: Nos valores fornecidos pela questão deu certo. O problema pode ser a presença de números nulos ou negativos, para os quais o _log_ não é definido nos reais. A propósito, a média geométrica do caso `B` é [12.5489...](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(15.03*10.20*12.89)%5E1%2F3), conforme encontrei [na minha consulta](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/40514)

Comment: @Motta, eu me acostumei a editar no smartphone... creio que no tablet seja ainda mais fácil. Obviamente esta resposta aqui não fora escrita a partir do smartphone, mas do notebook. Em compensação, [esta daqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/266198/64969) foi apenas smatphone, [esta outra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/265805/64969) eu usei bastante o smartphone, mas não lembro se foi só pra criar as imagens ou se foi pra tudo mesmo

Comment: @henriquew qual o conjunto de dados usados?

Comment: Boa tarde, meu erro foi o seguinte, dentro os vários registros que tinham, havian números do tipo (0.1 , 0.8 , 0.59), na "fórumula exp(sum(log(valor))/count(*)) as media_geo" acontecia então o erro "Ocorreu uma operação de ponto flutuante inválida." Obrigado a todos!

Comment: @henriquew não tive problemas com esses dados na fórmula. Coloquei esses 3 valores. Testei com 15 valores desse naipe e não obtive problemas

Comment: Tente com os seguintes valores (167.00
68.00
1876.00
225.00
2732.00
3754.00
9999.00
231.00
340.00
946.00
163.00
3348.00
819.00
1426.00
148.00
618.00
5721.00
1753.00
1978.00
3828.00
1104.00) ou (0.57
0.88
1.63
1.38
0.32
0.57
1.32
1.38
2.22
0.79
3.85
0.46
0.63
0.86
0.88
0.86
2.19
1.47
0.32
0.82
2.40) na  formula "exp(sum(log(ANSDET.VALOR))/count(*)) as VALOR"

Comment: [Média de 882.011621537022, e média de 0.9984505031117724](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/41027). Usei o agrupador `D` para o primeiro conjunto de números, e `E` para o segundo conjunto

Comment: Meus resultados não foram perfeitos, mas fiz o melhor que pude nas operações que o SQL Server fornece. Cada cálculo com ponto flutuante implica em perder precisão [1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/286014/64969) [2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/64969) [3](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/272376/64969).

Comment: Veja o resultado para [`D`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=geometric+mean(167.00,68.00,1876.00,225.00,2732.00,3754.00,9999.00,231.00,340.00,946.00,163.00,3348.00,819.00,1426.00,148.00,618.00,5721.00,1753.00,1978.00,3828.00,1104.00)), e para [`E`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=geometric+mean(0.57,0.88,1.63,1.38,0.32,0.57,1.32,1.38,2.22,0.79,3.85,0.46,0.63,0.86,0.88,0.86,2.19,1.47,0.32,0.82,2.40)). Note que só perdi precisão em `D`, em `E` foi uma resposta satisfatória

Answer (score 0):

```
--li ponderada e nao geometrica
--usando a propriedade dos logs se tem o produto
exp(sum(log(valor)))
--calcule a raiz
power(exp(sum(log(valor))),(1/(count(*)))
--isto deve resolver para números pequenos
```

Comment: Utilizando estas formulas recebo o seguinte erro, "Ocorreu uma operação de ponto flutuante inválida."