# Acumular rentabilidade (matemática financeira) - MySQL

Tags: mysql, matemática

Gostaria de ajudar para criar uma função ou fórmula, no MySQL, onde eu consiga acumular índices (rentabilidade, inflação, etc). Neste caso específico, quero acumular rentabilidade de um fundo, em um período determinado. Tenho uma tabela contendo vários fundos e rentabilidade mensal de cada um. Exemplo:

Mês/Fundo/Rentabilidade: 2023-01-01 ABC 1,00%; 2023-02-01 ABC 0,50%; 2023-03-01 ABC 1,20%;

O resultado acumulado para este período é: ( (1 + 1,00%) x (1 + 0,50%) x (1 + 1,20%) ) - 1 = 2,72%

Tentei da seguinte forma:

select fundo, SUM(1+rentabilidade) as rentabilidade_acumulada from tab_fundos where fundo = 'ABC' and mes_ano between '2023-01-01' and '2023-03-01' group by fundo

Não conheço uma função que faria o processo de multiplicação de todos os registros, como um SUM faria para somar tudo.

Comment: Veja se ajuda .... https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/372811/calcular-m%c3%a9dia-geom%c3%a9trica-em-consulta-sql

Comment: Considerando que [esta pergunta já foi feita faz pouco tempo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/588192/70) e instruções já foram dadas, o espaço de comentários foi desativado nesta duplicata para evitar descentralização de conteúdo, mas está disponível naquela postagem, e pode ser usado quando restaurada. Restaure-a e edite conforme links passados, que automaticamente ela entra numa revisão da comunidade dos pontos e fechamento.